# Join 2 ambiguous SQL tables

Tags: sql, azure, apache-spark

I have 2 tables that I want to join, when I try it gives me error of "ambiguous" the thing is both tables after joining them should generate new rows since values will match more than 1 time.

table_1

| row_a | row_b | row_c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | True | 1992 |
| abc | False | 1992 |

table_2

| row_c | row_d | row_e |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1992 | old | expired |
| 1992 | new | recent |

I want to join them and create

| row_a | row_b | row_c | row_d | row_e |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | True | 1992 | old | expired |
| abc | True | 1992 | new | recent |
| abc | False | 1992 | old | expired |
| abc | False | 1992 | new | recent |

It has to be in SQL create new table, no python or anything else like it. In reality the code needs to join based on 2 columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CROSS JOIN](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-join.html) gets you the wanted result

```
SELECT row_a,row_b,table_1.row_c,row_d, row_e FROM table_1 CROSS JOIN table_2;
```

Comment: When I try to do it, it says it found "duplicate columns"

Comment: yes row_c is double, i added the column from table_1

Comment: @RandomPerson - CROSS JOINs can be useful. Just be sure you understand what a cartesian product means in this context, as it can generate a large number or records